# Detecting own down time?

Tags: linux

Is there a tool to detect the downtime of a own server?

Something like a program which is pinging another server every 30 seconds and write it into a file, so that you can read the file and see when your server was down. (When your server is down there are no entrys for a time)

Since some months I get sometimes randomly disconnected for ~3 seconds from my server, so I want to monitor if it is a serverproblem

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are plenty of solution for your problem. Those solutions are often referred to as monitoring systems. You can easily set up one, which will monitor your server, record performance statistics and provide them in useful way.

I really don't want to mention a specific product. But I think I can provide few examples based on how the monitoring systems are working.

Some have agents, which get installed on the remote systems and send data to the monitoring server. Others work over SNMP - they `poll` the monitored host and record the data, they could also receive notifications from that host (SNMP Traps). Other systems combine both ways - agent and SNMP.

Windows has a proprietary protocol (middleware might fit better as a description) - WMI. It's quite powerful and some monitoring systems use it to get data for monitored hosts.

I hope this helps you.